# ¿Cómo diseñar un DataFrame MultiIndex con niveles incluidos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un archivo .xlsx y me gustaría obtenerlo en el formato de un MultiIndex.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Conozco como obtener los valores de la primera o segunda columna.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

wb = load_workbook(filename='Trees.xlsx')

# Test if the cell values are "Division", if it is the case, store it
divisions = (cell.value for cell in wb['Industry']['A']
                 if cell.data_type == "s" and "Division" in cell.value)

# loop over the second cell, check wether there is already something in the first column
sub_divisions = (cell.value for cell in wb['Industry']['B']
                 if cell.data_type == "s")
```

No sé cómo encajar uno dentro del otro. Intenté lo siguiente :

```
for cell in wb['Industry']['A']:
    if cell.data_type == "s" and "Division" in cell.value:
        divisions = divisions + cell.value
        for sub_cell in wb['Industry']['B'] # How to add the condition : from the row just below the one which had the last division
            if ((sub_cell.data_type == "s") and ("Division" not in cell['A'][cell.row+1].value)):
                sub_divisions = sub_divisions + sub_cell
```

No funciona solamente es un borrado.

Un amigo me anconsejé utilisar ElastiSearch con indexes y pensaba tambien utilisar lo que parece llamarse SIC en la primera columna.

El archivo .xlsx esta [aqui](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CiarXio69ypMQAy-C3yDXE5mV6UZqKqP/view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy del todo seguro del tipo de salida que esperas.

De la estructura de la excel se deduce que la columna "A" tiene mezcladas dos cosas:

- Texto que son una especie de "encabezados" de primer nivel, tales como `"Division A: Agriculture, Forestry, And Fishing"`, etc. Delante de cada uno de estos "títulos" parece haber una línea en blanco.
- Números que aparentemente son una especie de código y que entiendo que serían los "datos" finales del dataframe

En la columna B aparecen básicamente cadenas de texto que actuarían como "encabezados de segundo nivel", y líneas en blanco, en las que hay que presuponer que seguimos bajo el mismo encabezado de segundo nivel, salvo que aparezca un encabezado de primer nivel nuevo en la columna anterior.

Lo mismo cabe decir para la columna C y la D.

Por tanto entiendo que lo que quieres es almacenar en realidad los números que aparecen en la columna A, pero indexados (con un índice multi-nivel) según los textos de las columnas A (cuando aparezca), B, C y D.

El problema es bastante difícil porque la hoja no está bien estructurada, ya que mirando una columna sólo, como por ejemplo la C, mientras veamos celdas vacías no es fácil saber cuando seguimos dentro de la misma subcategoría C, o cuando hemos cambiado ya de sub-categoría (porque en las columnas A o B han aparecido categorías nuevas).

También entiendo que cuando aparece una categoría nueva en las columnas a la izquierda, la categoría de la columna actual "se resetea" por así decir a un valor neutro que viene a significar "no hay subcategoría todavía" y que he optado por representar como "---".

### Solución propuesta

Esta es la solución que propongo (voy mostrando cómo va quedando el datframe tras cada paso para que se entienda mejor):

#### 1. Leer la hoja

Tras leerla elimino la primera fila que estaba vacía, y renombro las columnas a letras para que sea más manejable:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel("Trees.xlsx")[1:]
df.columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

Aspecto de df (10 primeras filas):

```
                                A                             B                              C                 D
1   Division A: Agriculture, F...                           NaN                            NaN               NaN
2                             100  Agricultural production-crop                            NaN               NaN
3                             110                           NaN                    Cash grains               NaN
4                             111                           NaN                            NaN             Wheat
5                             112                           NaN                            NaN              Rice
6                             115                           NaN                            NaN              Corn
7                             116                           NaN                            NaN          Soybeans
8                             119                           NaN                            NaN  Cash grains, nec
9                             130                           NaN  Field crops, except cash g...               NaN
10                            131                           NaN                            NaN            Cotton
```

#### 2. Separar los números en la columna A a otra columna (E)

Crearé  una nueva columna (E) que contenga esos números, o bien el texto "---" cuando en A no hay número. A la vez, eliminaré los números de la columna A (cambiándolos por `NaN`) para dejar sólo los textos:

```
df['E'] = df.A.apply(lambda x: x if type(x)==int else "---")
df.A = df.A.apply(lambda x: np.nan if type(x) == int else x)
```

Aspecto de df ahora:

```
                                A                             B                              C                 D    E
1   Division A: Agriculture, F...                           NaN                            NaN               NaN  ---
2                             NaN  Agricultural production-crop                            NaN               NaN  100
3                             NaN                           NaN                    Cash grains               NaN  110
4                             NaN                           NaN                            NaN             Wheat  111
5                             NaN                           NaN                            NaN              Rice  112
6                             NaN                           NaN                            NaN              Corn  115
7                             NaN                           NaN                            NaN          Soybeans  116
8                             NaN                           NaN                            NaN  Cash grains, nec  119
9                             NaN                           NaN  Field crops, except cash g...               NaN  130
10                            NaN                           NaN                            NaN            Cotton  131
```

#### 3. Rellenar encabezados de nivel 2, 3, etc. cuando se "resetean"

Cada vez que aparece un encabezado nuevo en el nivel N, todos los de niveles inferiores (N+1, N+2, ...) se "resetean" (les asigno "---"):

```
df.B = np.where(pd.notnull(df.A), "---", df.B)
df.C = np.where(pd.notnull(df.B), "---", df.C)
df.D = np.where(pd.notnull(df.C), "---", df.D)
```

Nuevo aspecto de df:

```
                               A                             B                              C                 D    E
1   Division A: Agriculture, F...                           ---                            ---               ---  ---
2                             NaN  Agricultural production-crop                            ---               ---  100
3                             NaN                           NaN                    Cash grains               ---  110
4                             NaN                           NaN                            NaN             Wheat  111
5                             NaN                           NaN                            NaN              Rice  112
6                             NaN                           NaN                            NaN              Corn  115
7                             NaN                           NaN                            NaN          Soybeans  116
8                             NaN                           NaN                            NaN  Cash grains, nec  119
9                             NaN                           NaN  Field crops, except cash g...               ---  130
10                            NaN                           NaN                            NaN            Cotton  131
```

#### 4. Eliminar los NaN de los encabezados

Cada vez que en una columna aparece un encabezado nuevo, de ahí hacia abajo rellenaré todos los `NaN` con ese encabezado. Gracias a que antes puse "---" en ciertos lugares, esos hacen de "freno" para detener el relleno:

```
df = df.fillna(method="pad")
```

Nuevo aspecto de df:

```
                                A                             B                              C                 D    E
1   Division A: Agriculture, F...                           ---                            ---               ---  ---
2   Division A: Agriculture, F...  Agricultural production-crop                            ---               ---  100
3   Division A: Agriculture, F...  Agricultural production-crop                    Cash grains               ---  110
4   Division A: Agriculture, F...  Agricultural production-crop                    Cash grains             Wheat  111
5   Division A: Agriculture, F...  Agricultural production-crop                    Cash grains              Rice  112
6   Division A: Agriculture, F...  Agricultural production-crop                    Cash grains              Corn  115
7   Division A: Agriculture, F...  Agricultural production-crop                    Cash grains          Soybeans  116
8   Division A: Agriculture, F...  Agricultural production-crop                    Cash grains  Cash grains, nec  119
9   Division A: Agriculture, F...  Agricultural production-crop  Field crops, except cash g...               ---  130
10  Division A: Agriculture, F...  Agricultural production-crop  Field crops, except cash g...            Cotton  131
```

#### 5. Multi-index

¡Finalmente! Con los datos de encabezados así replicados, podemos crear un dataframe multi-índice usando como índices las columnas A, B, C y D y como datos finales los de la columna E:

```
df = df.set_index(['A','B','C','D'])
```

Aspecto final (15 primeras filas):

```
A                              B                            C                              D                                  
Division A: Agriculture, Fo... ---                          ---                            ---                             ---
                               Agricultural production-crop ---                            ---                             100
                                                            Cash grains                    ---                             110
                                                                                           Wheat                           111
                                                                                           Rice                            112
                                                                                           Corn                            115
                                                                                           Soybeans                        116
                                                                                           Cash grains, nec                119
                                                            Field crops, except cash gr... ---                             130
                                                                                           Cotton                          131
                                                                                           Tobacco                         132
                                                                                           Sugarcane and sugar beets       133
                                                                                           Irish potatoes                  134
                                                                                           Field crops, except cash gr...  139
                                                            Vegetables and melons          ---                             160
```

Versión tabla-html del resultado final, donde se aprecia mejor la estructura del multi-índice:

[image: Tabla html]

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Espero un poquito antes darle la recompensa si alguien alguna vez intentó hacer otra respuesta. Pero esto esta lo que esperaba. Sabes como puedo crear un systema de consulta gracias al multiindex? Básicamente, quiero poder seleccionar los elementos en la primera columna, incluirá todo lo que está debajo y luego implementaríamos las opciones incluidas para permitir al usuario tomar decisiones más precisas

Comment: Por ejemplo, ¿cómo enviar al usuario la primera columna para comenzar?

Comment: @Marine1 Veo que has publicado otra pregunta sobre este tema. Mira [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/164256/7123) que espero sea lo que buscas.